# D3 Javascript loop doesn't render

Tags: javascript, html, oop, d3.js

I've written a quick bit of Javascript in D3, using an objected oriented approach (see `Org` class).  I'd like to have the circles smoothly animate between random (x,y) locations, however the code I've written gets stuck without rendering anything (white page, spinner).  If I exclude the `while(true)`, the circles render beautifully, but I need them to animate - please help!

My second question is does it make sense to use D3 in this object oriented way?  In a class OOP language like Java I would do something like  `orgs[x].width++` and call some kind of rerender function, but with D3 do those references to memory hold, or do I have to update the circle data every time it changes (i.e. `circles.data(orgs)`)?

```
class Org {
    constructor(_width, _height) {
        this.width = _width;
        this.height = _height;
    }
}

var canvas = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', screen.width)
        .attr('height', screen.height);

var orgs = d3.range(100).map(function() {
    return new Org(Math.random() * screen.width, Math.random() * screen.height);
});

var circles = canvas.selectAll("circle")
        .data(orgs)
        .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('cx', d => d.width )
        .attr('cy', d => d.height )
        .attr('r', 5)
        .attr('fill', 'rgb(255, 0, 213)');

while (true) { //Sticks without rendering
    this.update();
}

function update() {
    circles.transition()
        .attr('cx', function() { return Math.random() * screen.width; })
        .attr('cy', function() { return Math.random() * screen.height; });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `while(true)` without a `break` will loop forever (infinite loop), because `true` is always true. You can do:

```
while (true) {
    this.update();
    break;
}
```

To make `update` run just once.

Besides that, bear in mind that if you don't specify the `duration()` of the transition, D3 sets a default duration of 250ms. From the API:

> If a duration is not specified, it defaults to 250ms

So, each function cancels the precedent one and nothing happens. If you want a repeating `update` use a different approach, like a recursion or `setInterval`, but not this `while(true)`.

(regarding your second question, it seems "too broad" for S.O. and, therefore, I'll refrain from giving my opinion, but I reckon it's not a common approach among D3 community)